# Show $A$ hermitian $\iff v^tA\overline{v}\in\Bbb R$ for all $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that a matrix $A \in M(n \times n, \mathbb{C})$ is hermitian iff $v^tA\overline{v} \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: I think you need nothing more than knowing that $x=v^\intercal A\bar{v}$ is a scalar, whence $x^\intercal=x$. A number $x$ is real if $\bar{x}=x$.

EDIT: More thoroughly, $A$ is Hermitian iff $\overline{A^\intercal}=A$. Then $\overline{x}=\overline{x^\intercal}=\overline{\bar{v}^\intercal A^\intercal v}=v^\intercal\overline{A^\intercal}\bar{v}=v^\intercal A\bar{v}=x$. Hence $x$ is real.

Conversely, if $\bar{x}=x$, then $v^\intercal A\bar{v}=\bar{v}^\intercal A^\intercal v=v^\intercal \overline{A^\intercal}\bar{v}$, whence $\overline{A^\intercal}=A$ since the relation holds for all $v$.

Comment: I think it will more relevant if you explain why $\bar{v}^{t}Bv=0 \Longrightarrow B=0$.

Comment: @user10676 But this implication, that $B=0$, does not hold. Or you mean $B=A-\overline{A^\intercal}$?

Answer (score 0):

Check this file, Theorem 8.10. [hermitian](http://college.cengage.com/mathematics/larson/elementary_linear/4e/shared/downloads/c08s5.pdf)

Comment: I feel like this should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: [Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)